# Is it possible to fix library parametrized type implementation on the client side to prevent unchecked warning?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, unchecked

I have used JSON library from external provider (google code project) which have a class `JSONArray` defined this way:

```
public class JSONArray extends ArrayList implements List , ... {
```

So it has a `Collection`'s method `.addAll( Collection<? extends E> elements )` but of course, simple usage:

```
JSONArray someData = new JSONArray();
someData.addAll( Arrays.asList( new String[] {"a","b"} ) );
```

rises unchecked warning, same with explicit call to `Arrays.<String>asList`.

Is there a way to remove this warning without marking whole method with @SuppressWarnings or extract this operation to another method with @SuppressWarnings?

Comment: Hmmm, running that code, using wink-json4j 1.3.0, I get no warnings. What library are you specificly using? I could not find any other JSONArray that would match the signature..